# Nodejs "local global var" for a new instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, global-variables, global

Today I hit the wall while writing TCP server in node js ... 
I need to make TCP server for windows and android app: Using just nodejs net module ... 
[image: server structure ?]

there is app class in with is called server class that creates several Client instances. one on each connection ...
And in each of these client instances, I need a global var that is visible in "current" instance of client...and recursively in all other instances, that's been invoked in client class instance.

I need that global var for holding session content like vars, objects, and crypt keys ... for all instances called in Client class instance and so one... without passing values to every new instane ...

```
//app.js
var Server = require("./core/server/Server");
console.log('hi!');
console.dir("there is nothing to look at at the momment");

global.DEBUG = true;
global.NEW_GUID = require('uuid/v4');

var server = new Server()
server.start();

//server.js
const net = require('net');
const Client = require("./Client");

class Server{
    constructor (port, address) {
        this.port = port || 4484;
        this.address = address || '127.0.0.1';
        this.clients = [];
      }
  start(callback) {
    let server = this; 
    server.connection = net.createServer((socket) => {
      socket.setEncoding("UTF8");
      let client = new Client(socket);
      server.clients.push(client);
      socket.on('error',(e)=>{ console.dir(e); })
      socket.on('end', () => {});
    });


    this.connection.listen(this.port, this.address);


  }

}
module.exports = Server;


//Client.js
//req some components
    GLOBAL_VAR = {
  login :"a",
  sess_crypt: "encryption instance setuped in client",
  socket:seocket
}
class Client {
    constructor(socket) {
      //some this vars        }
    async GetLogin() {
    }
    async GetData(d) {
    }
    StartDialog() {  
    }
    serverHandler(){
        console.log(`${this.name} connected.`);
      //client.GetLogin();
      this.socket.write("WELCOME\r\n")
      this.socket.on("data", (d) => {
        var ed = Buffer.from(d);
        console.dir(ed.toString("UTF8"));
        this.GetData(ed).then((r)=>{
          if (r.cmd == "LOGIN") {
            this.sth = new sth();
            this.sth.sth(); // inside this you can have multiple calls of sth and i can't pass any value by parameter because of rest "old" js code what was running on RHINo Java server that i can't modifi to much 
          }
        })
      })
    }
}
module.exports = Client;

    ///sth.js
//req some components
class sth extends other_staf{
  constructor() {
    this.login = GLOBAL_VAR.login
  }
  oninit(){
    // do staf start next instance of sth()
  }
  sth(){
    GLOBAL_VAR.socket.write(GLOBAL_VAR.sess_crypt("some request\r\n"))
    this.oninit();
  }
}
module.exports = sth;
```

Comment: What does "need to make sth" mean?  Is that a typo?

Comment: Why do you need a global var?  Object oriented development should start out with the goal of not needing global variables to make your code work.

Comment: From what I understand you need to use functions in your code if you define new Client(socket) inside function and use `var g_v = "client 1";` inside  that function it will only be accessible from the code that iside that function.

Comment: @jfriend00 I made that more clear ...

Comment: Sorry, but still don't understand what you're asking for or what problem you're asking us to help with.

Comment: if each client need to have different login then why don't you just save that login in `this` inside client?

Comment: @jfriend00 Just added some code. I can't pas any parameter into a new instance...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need global variables. You can try to do something like this, define data in Client so like so

```
var client = new Client();
client.data.name = "client 1";
```

or better pass it to contructor:

```
var client = new Client({name: "client 1"});
```

and in constructor use

```
function Client(options) {
    this.data = options;
    // ...
}
```

and pass client object to instances:

```
var instance = new instance(client);
```

and access:

```
instance.client.data.name;
```

if that box you have in proved image is the inside of the object then you can use this instead of instance and client.

Comment: I've added some code,,, and I can't pas any parameter into a new instance that I will call into client class